# Terraform error connection refused: wrongly using localhost

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-kubernetes

Have successfully been using terraform for about a month. Used `terraform apply` to create many resources on Azure (i.e. `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster`, `kubernetes_service`).

I am suddenly getting the below error regarding my kubernetes service.

```
╷
│ Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name>": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
│ 
│   with kubernetes_service.<service name>,
│   on main.tf line 132, in resource "kubernetes_service" "<service name>":
│  132: resource "kubernetes_service" "<service name>" {
│ 
╵
```

**I can't figure out why suddenly this URL is referencing `localhost`, should be Azure. I am unsure what could have changed this.**

- I am using the correct kubectl context.
- `kubectl config view` returns correct cluster details
- `kubectl cluster-info` returns correct azure endpoints
- Verified the service is available in Azure Portal
- Updated terraform to latest version
- Ran apply with debug:

```
2023-11-05T16:14:31.939-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: 2023/11/05 16:14:31 [INFO] Checking service <service name>
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: 2023/11/05 16:14:31 [DEBUG] Kubernetes API Request Details:
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: ---[ REQUEST ]---------------------------------------
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: GET /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name> HTTP/1.1
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: Host: localhost
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: User-Agent: HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.6.3
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: Accept: application/json, */*
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5
2023-11-05T16:14:31.940-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2023-11-05T16:14:31.942-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: 2023/11/05 16:14:31 [DEBUG] Received error: &url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name>", Err:(*net.OpError)(0x14001036a50)}
2023-11-05T16:14:31.944-0500 [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.23.0_x5: Response contains error diagnostic: diagnostic_summary="Get \"http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name>\": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused" tf_req_id=ab63a5a7-5bab-fc9a-c4f2-c7b102614920 tf_resource_type=kubernetes_service @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.2/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 tf_rpc=ReadResource diagnostic_detail="" tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_provider_addr=registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_severity=ERROR timestamp=2023-11-05T16:14:31.943-0500
2023-11-05T16:14:31.944-0500 [ERROR] vertex "kubernetes_service.<service name>" error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name>": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
2023-11-05T16:14:31.944-0500 [ERROR] vertex "kubernetes_service.<service name> (expand)" error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name>": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
```

Providers in terraform file

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.72.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.23.0"
    }
    cloudflare = {
      source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = "4.15.0"
    }
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "cloudflare" {
  api_token = var.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN
}

...

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

...
```

Comment: Local context kubectl context shouldn't impact TF. Can you show your provider config for `kubernetes` provider?

Comment: could you please check your Kubernetes provider config, it seems that the provider might be using an incorrect configuration.  

Sharing that Kubernetes provider config would be also helpful for a better answer.

Comment: Hey @jordanm I have added the above providers in the terraform file. Configurations have allowed me to successfully deploy everything until this point.

Comment: @ishuar unfortunately the configuration is pretty straightforward... unsure what would account for the change to start using `localhost`. Not using K8s locally, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you have some environmental variable set that affects this?

Comment: @JohnDoe did you run `terraform plan` before trying to apply?

Comment: @MarkoE both `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` fail with the same error detailed above. I also cannot output variables like `aks_kube_config`, for instance, because it is all `(known after apply)`. Good thought though.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would refresh the credentials but too bad it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/<service name>": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
```

The error occurred because the `Terraform plan` indicated a planned replacement of the `AKS` cluster. consequently, when the planning process reached the `Kubernetes provider` configuration, there was no known `AKS cluster endpoint`, causing the provider to default connecting to **localhost**.

To resolve the issue and connect to your `AKS cluster`, you can use the following configuration in your `provider "kubernetes`.

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}
```

The `config_path` specifies the path to your `Kubernetes configuration` file (`~/.kube/config` ). This file contains  the all necessary configuration details for accessing `AKS cluster`, including the cluster's `API server URL, client certificate, and client key`.

If you specify the `host`, `client_certificate`, `client_key`, and `cluster_ca_certificate` information in the `Kubernetes provider`, you must execute `terraform plan` with the target as shown below. This configuration enables you to connect to your `AKS cluster` instead of the `local host`.

`terraform plan -target *name of the your AKS cluster*`

```json
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "3.0.2"
        }
        kubernetes = {
          source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
          version = ">= 2.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    
    data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
      name                = "Venkat-aks"
      resource_group_name = "existing-RG"
    }
    
    provider "kubernetes" {
      config_path = "~/.kube/config"
    }
    
    resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
      metadata {
        name = "venkat-nginx"
        labels = {
          App = "venkatNginx"
        }
      }
    
      spec {
        replicas = 2
        selector {
          match_labels = {
            App = "VenkatNginx"
          }
        }
        template {
          metadata {
            labels = {
              App = "VenkatNginx"
            }
          }
          spec {
            container {
              image = "nginx:1.7.8"
              name  = "venkat"
    
              port {
                container_port = 80
              }
    
              resources {
                limits = {
                  cpu    = "0.5"
                  memory = "512Mi"
                }
                requests = {
                  cpu    = "250m"
                  memory = "50Mi"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx" {
      metadata {
        name = "nginx-venkat"
      }
      spec {
        selector = {
          App = kubernetes_deployment.nginx.spec.0.template.0.metadata[0].labels.App
        }
        port {
          port        = 80
          target_port = 80
        }
    
        type = "LoadBalancer"
      }
    }
```

**Terraform apply**

[image]

Once ran the terraform code, the deployment has been created.

[image]

Reference: [dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-get-http-localhost-api-v1-namespaces-dial-tcp-1-connect-connection-refused-after-upgrading-azurerm/33001)  by `apparentlymart`

Comment: While I am uncertain why providing the kubeconfig would be required well after successfully creating resources this helped reset things. I also had to subsequently use `terraform import` to associate the replaced cluster with the old one. I also needed to add a `temporary_name_for_rotation` to achieve this. I hope this is helpful to someone finding their terraform state in similar situation. Thanks @Venkat V.