# How to manage aks with terraform when AD enabled RBAC and local_account_disabled = true is set

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating aks cluster with Azure AD RBAC enabled and local account disabled.
Scenario:

- Create admin group
- Add admin id to group
- create resource group
- Provide "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role" in rg level to
  admin group
- Create aks cluster
- create namespace.

Everything is part of 1 main.tf file. But I get error Error: Unauthorized.
I am new to aks. Thanks for any help

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {

  }
} 
provider "azuread" {}  
data "azuread_user" "aad" {
  mail_nickname = "madhurshukla23jan_gmail.com#EXT#"
} 
resource "azuread_group" "k8sadmins" {
  display_name = "Kubernetes Admins"
  members = [
    data.azuread_user.aad.object_id,
  ]
  security_enabled = true
} 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources131"
  location = "West Europe"
} 
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  depends_on           = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role"
  principal_id         = azuread_group.k8sadmins.object_id
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "example-aks131"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks131"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
    managed                = true
    azure_rbac_enabled     = true
    admin_group_object_ids = [azuread_group.k8sadmins.id]
  }
  local_account_disabled = true

  service_principal {
    client_id     = "xxxxxx"
    client_secret = "xxxxxx"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "your-namespace-name-test13"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same issue for last 2 days and found a solution applicable for my case, probably it will help you too.

Usually to perform it on clusters without `AD Authentication with RBAC` enabled it's enough to take kubeconfig from resource output and then reuse it for "kubernetes" provider like

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.current.kube_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}
```

but to manage cluster in same apply session after creation following IaC in my case helped using `kube_admin_config` instead of `kube_config` like

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.current.kube_admin_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}
```

Not fully sure, but may help in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
How to manage aks with terraform when AD enabled RBAC and local_account_disabled = true is set
```

This error occurs because the `Provider: kubernetes` does not have the proper permission to create a namespace in your cluster.

[image]

To resolve the issue, ensure that `~/.kube/config` is specified in the provider rather than passing the details manually. Additionally, make sure to have the `Kubernetes Cluster Administrator` role.

```yaml
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}
```

The `config_path` specifies the path to your `Kubernetes configuration` file (`~/.kube/config` ). This file contains the all necessary configuration details for accessing `AKS cluster`, including the cluster's `API server URL, client certificate, and client key`.
Here is the updated code to create `AKS cluster` with `Name space`.

```json
   provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.15.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}

data "azuread_user" "ad1m" {
  user_principal_name = "user1"
}

data "azuread_user" "ad2" {
  user_principal_name = "user2.com"
}

data "azuread_user" "ad3" {
  user_principal_name = "user3.onmicrosoft.com"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
  name     = "aks_rg"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azuread_group" "aksadmngroup" {
  display_name     = "Kubernetes Admins"
  members          = [data.azuread_user.ad1m.object_id, data.azuread_user.ad2.object_id, data.azuread_user.ad3.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role"
  principal_id         = azuread_group.aksadmngroup.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "venkat_demo-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "venkataks"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
    managed                = true
    azure_rbac_enabled     = true
    admin_group_object_ids = [azuread_group.aksadmngroup.id]
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  local_account_disabled = true
  tags = {
    Environment = "testing"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "venkat-test13"
  }
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Reference: [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427746/terraform-error-connection-refused-wrongly-using-localhost/77429765#77429765) answer provided by me

[Kubernetes Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#example-usage)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added below 
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role"
  principal_id         = azuread_group.k8sadmins.object_id
} 
However still getting Unauthorized.
May be I am doing something wrong, can you redirect me to a github repo where you have the source code for the implementation.
Also how to populate config file, on which step it will be created.

Comment: I have provided the source code in the answer. Please change the provider as follows:
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}

Comment: I have edited my implementation above with the changes you suggested.

Comment: Hi @Madhur, Are you still facing the same issue after changing the provider configuration to "kubernetes" { config_path = "~/.kube/config" }

Comment: Hi @Madhur, I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: yes @venkat. Still same error after changing provider

Comment: Could you please verify that you have the Kubernetes Cluster Administrator role and see if you can create a Name space from the portal?